# Add css class element to Bootstrap Card only when last checkbox inside is checeked (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I have a working jQuery srcipt that when a checkbox is checked it will add 1 Class and toggle another, and it works like it should when only one checkbox is inside, but when I place multiple inside it I need it only to change the class when the last checkbox is checked inside it .. how can I achive this in jQuery? .. should I group them or somthing similar?

Please see following example and code :

```js
$("input[type='checkbox']:last-child").change(function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $(this).closest(".card").find(".card-header").addClass("text-white bg-success");
    $(this).closest(".card").toggleClass("border-success");
  } else {
    $(this).closest(".card").find(".card-header").removeClass("text-white bg-success");
    $(this).closest(".card").toggleClass("border-success");
  }
});

<!-- Original Script below this line for history concern

$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $(this).closest(".card").find(".card-header").addClass("text-white bg-success");
    $(this).closest(".card").toggleClass("border-success");
  } else {
    $(this).closest(".card").find(".card-header").removeClass("text-white bg-success");
    $(this).closest(".card").toggleClass("border-success");
  }
});

-->
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Demo</title>

  <style>
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    .inside-label {
      cursor: pointer;
      user-select: none;
      padding: 6px 8px;
      border-radius: 8px;
      overflow: hidden;
      transition: all 0.2s ease;
    }
    
    .inside-label:not(:last-child) {
      margin-right: 6px;
    }
    
    .inside-label:hover {
      background: #d2fcdc;
    }
    
    .inside-label span {
      float: left;
      vertical-align: middle;
      transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
      font-weight: 800;
    }
    
    .inside-label-20 span:first-child {
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
    }
    
    .inside-label-30 span:first-child {
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
    }
    
    .inside-label-40 span:first-child {
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;
    }
    
    .inside-label-50 span:first-child {
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
    }
    
    .inside-label-60 span:first-child {
      width: 60px;
      height: 60px;
    }
    
    .inside-label-100 span:first-child {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
    }
    
    .inside-label span:first-child {
      position: relative;
      border-radius: 4px;
      transform: scale(1);
      border: 2px solid #c8ccd4;
      transition: all 0.2s ease;
    }
    
    .inside-label span:first-child svg {
      position: absolute;
      top: 2px;
      left: 1px;
      fill: none;
      stroke: #fff;
      stroke-width: 2;
      stroke-linecap: round;
      stroke-linejoin: round;
      stroke-dasharray: 16px;
      stroke-dashoffset: 16px;
      transition: all 0.3s ease;
      transition-delay: 0.1s;
      transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
    
    .inside-label span:last-child {
      padding-left: 8px;
      line-height: 18px;
    }
    
    .inside-label:hover span:first-child {
      border-color: #28a745;
    }
    
    .main:checked+.inside-label span:first-child {
      background: #28a745;
      border-color: #28a745;
      animation: myAnimation 0.4s ease;
    }
    
    .main:checked+.inside-label span:first-child svg {
      stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
    
    .tick-icon {
      position: absolute;
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      pointer-events: none;
      user-select: none;
    }
    
    @media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
      .inside-label {
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 4px;
        display: inline-block;
      }
      body {
        width: auto;
        display: inherit;
        padding: 20px;
      }
    }
    
    @keyframes myAnimation {
      50% {
        transform: scale(0.9);
      }
    }
  </style>


</head>

<body>

  <svg class="tick-icon">
    <symbol id="check-tick" viewbox="0 0 12 10">
        <polyline points="1.5 6 4.5 9 10.5 1"></polyline>
    </symbol>
</svg>


  <table cellpadding="10">
    <tr>
      <td valign="top">

        <div class="card" style="width: 300px;">
          <div class="card-header " align="center" style="width: 300px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">Multiple Demo</div>
          <div class="card-body" align="center">


            <table style="width: 250px;" cellpadding="3">

              <tr style="border-bottom: 0px solid #FFFFFF;">
                <td style="width: 200px; height: 50px;" valign="top" align="left">

                  <DIV style="margin-top: 15px;">
                    <font style="font-size: 14px;"><b>Multiple Demo 1</b></font>
                  </DIV>

                </td>
                <td style="width: 50px; height: 50px;" valign="top" align="center">

                  <input class="main" type="checkbox" value="yes" name="md1" id="md1" style="display: none;" />
                  <label class="inside-label inside-label-40" for="md1"><span>
                            <svg width="90%" height="80%">
                                <use xlink:href="#check-tick"></use>
                            </svg></span></label>

                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr style="border-bottom: 0px solid #FFFFFF;">
                <td style="width: 200px; height: 50px;" valign="top" align="left">

                  <DIV style="margin-top: 15px;">
                    <font style="font-size: 14px;"><b>Multiple Demo 2</b></font>
                  </DIV>

                </td>
                <td style="width: 50px; height: 50px;" valign="top" align="center">

                  <input class="main" type="checkbox" value="yes" name="md2" id="md2" style="display: none;" />
                  <label class="inside-label inside-label-40" for="md2"><span>
                            <svg width="90%" height="80%">
                                <use xlink:href="#check-tick"></use>
                            </svg></span></label>

                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr style="border-bottom: 0px solid #FFFFFF;">
                <td style="width: 200px; height: 50px;" valign="top" align="left">

                  <DIV style="margin-top: 15px;">
                    <font style="font-size: 14px;"><b>Multiple Demo 3</b></font>
                  </DIV>

                </td>
                <td style="width: 50px; height: 50px;" valign="top" align="center">

                  <input class="main" type="checkbox" value="yes" name="md3" id="md3" style="display: none;" />
                  <label class="inside-label inside-label-40" for="md3"><span>
                            <svg width="90%" height="80%">
                                <use xlink:href="#check-tick"></use>
                            </svg></span></label>

                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>

      </td>
      <td valign="top">

        <div class="card" style="width: 300px;">
          <div class="card-header " align="center" style="width: 300px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">Single Demo</div>
          <div class="card-body" align="center">


            <table style="width: 250px;" cellpadding="3">

              <tr style="border-bottom: 0px solid #FFFFFF;">
                <td style="width: 200px; height: 50px;" valign="top" align="left">

                  <DIV style="margin-top: 15px;">
                    <font style="font-size: 14px;"><b>Single Demo 1</b></font>
                  </DIV>

                </td>
                <td style="width: 50px; height: 50px;" valign="top" align="center">

                  <input class="main" type="checkbox" value="yes" name="sd1" id="sd1" style="display: none;" />
                  <label class="inside-label inside-label-40" for="sd1"><span>
                            <svg width="90%" height="80%">
                                <use xlink:href="#check-tick"></use>
                            </svg></span></label>

                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>

      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>


  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I'd do it is to find the total number of checkboxes (event trigger + siblings), then the number of checked siblings. If the total is equal to the number of checked, apply the style.

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
  var parent = $(this).closest('table');
  var siblings = $(parent).find('input[type="checkbox"]');
  var checkedSibs = $(parent).find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
  if (siblings.length === checkedSibs.length){
    $(this).closest(".card").find(".card-header").addClass("text-white bg-success");
    $(this).closest(".card").toggleClass("border-success");
  } else {
    $(this).closest(".card").find(".card-header").removeClass("text-white bg-success");
    $(this).closest(".card").toggleClass("border-success");
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi @thatguytyler .. thank you for your answer .. the code works but only when you have checked all and start uncheck again ..I have updated snippet so you can see what I mean.